# How a process release a redis lock which was not owned by this process?

Tags: redis-py, readwritelock

I tried to implement a simple read-preferred read-write lock using 2 mutexes (using redis.lock.Lock), like what is described in this link (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Readers%E2%80%93writer_lock)

In the **[End Read]** steps, I encountered this problem:

**If b = 0, unlock g** #(a write lock).

As, this READ process is not the one that acquired the lock, so the system throws an error. I think it has some token stored somewhere, and I can get it to use for the lock release, but I am not sure.

Could someone give me a hint? Thanks.

```
from enum import Enum
from redis import StrictRedis, lock
# data in Redis cache:

# "read_counter_lock_name" : 0
# "read_lock_lock_name" -> read lock, protect "read_counter_lock_name"
# "write_lock_lock_name" -> write lock, protect write data section

class Prefix(Enum):
    READ = 'read_lock_'
    WRITE = 'write_lock_'
    READ_COUNTER = 'read_counter_'

class RedisLockParams(Enum):
    TIMEOUT = 60 # maximum life for the lock in seconds = 60 seconds
    SLEEP_TIME = 0.1 # the amount of time to sleep in seconds per loop iteration
                    # in redis lock's acquire() - sleep then retry
    BLOCKING = True # acquire() should block until the lock has been acquired
    BLOCKING_TIMEOUT = None # maximum amount of time in seconds to spend trying
                            # to acquire the lock


class ReadWriteLock:
    def __init__(self, lock_name: str, redis_host: str, redis_port: int, redis_key: str):
        self.__read_lock_name = Prefix.READ.value + lock_name
        self.__write_lock_name = Prefix.WRITE.value + lock_name
        self.__read_counter_key = Prefix.READ_COUNTER.value + lock_name
        # self.__redis_host = redis_host
        # self.__redis_port = redis_port
        # self.__redis_key = redis_key
        self.__cache = StrictRedis(host = redis_host,
                                port = redis_port,
                                db=0, # up to 16 logical database
                                password = redis_key,
                                ssl=True)
        print(f'ping return:{self.__cache.ping()}')
        # set the read counter to 0, if it does not exist.
        self.__cache.setnx(self.__read_counter_key, 0)

        # init the read lock
        self.__read_lock = lock.Lock(self.__cache,
                                    self.__read_lock_name,
                                    RedisLockParams.TIMEOUT.value,
                                    RedisLockParams.SLEEP_TIME.value,
                                    RedisLockParams.BLOCKING.value,
                                    RedisLockParams.BLOCKING_TIMEOUT.value)
        
        # init the write lock
        self.__write_lock = lock.Lock(self.__cache,
                                    self.__write_lock_name,
                                    RedisLockParams.TIMEOUT.value,
                                    RedisLockParams.SLEEP_TIME.value,
                                    RedisLockParams.BLOCKING.value,
                                    RedisLockParams.BLOCKING_TIMEOUT.value)
        

    def acquire_read_lock(self) -> bool:
        write_lock_acquired = False

        self.__read_lock.acquire()
        read_counter = self.__cache.incr(self.__read_counter_key)
        if (read_counter == 1):
            write_lock_acquired = self.__write_lock.acquire() # acquire write lock
        self.__read_lock.release()

        return write_lock_acquired

    def release_read_lock(self):
        read_lock_acquired = self.__read_lock.acquire()
        read_counter = self.__cache.decr(self.__read_counter_key)
        
        if read_counter == 0 and read_lock_acquired:
            self.__write_lock.release() # release the write lock-> issue!!!
        
        self.__read_lock.release()

    def acquire_write_lock(self) -> bool:
        return self.__write_lock.acquire()

    def release_write_lock(self):
        self.__write_lock.release()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured out how to release the not-owned redis lock by taking a look at the redis' python library source code. Below is the modified version of the multiread-single-write lock class.

```
# read_write_lock.py
from enum import Enum
from redis import StrictRedis, lock
# data in Redis cache:

# "read_counter_lock_name" : 0
# "read_lock_lock_name" -> read lock, protect "read_counter_lock_name"
# "write_lock_lock_name" -> write lock, protect write data section

class Prefix(Enum):
    READ = 'read_lock_'
    WRITE = 'write_lock_'
    READ_COUNTER = 'read_counter_'

class RedisLockParams(Enum):
    TIMEOUT = 60 # maximum life for the lock in seconds = 60 seconds
    SLEEP_TIME = 0.1 # the amount of time to sleep in seconds per loop iteration
                    # in redis lock's acquire() - sleep then retry
    BLOCKING = True # acquire() should block until the lock has been acquired
    BLOCKING_TIMEOUT = None # maximum amount of time in seconds to spend trying
                            # to acquire the lock


class ReadWriteLock:
    def __init__(self, lock_name: str, redis_host: str, redis_port: int, redis_key: str):
        self.__read_lock_name = Prefix.READ.value + lock_name
        self.__write_lock_name = Prefix.WRITE.value + lock_name
        self.__read_counter_key = Prefix.READ_COUNTER.value + lock_name

        self.__cache = StrictRedis(host = redis_host,
                                port = redis_port,
                                db=0, # up to 16 logical database
                                password = redis_key,
                                ssl=True)
        # set the read counter to 0, if it does not exist.
        self.__cache.setnx(self.__read_counter_key, 0)

        # init the read lock
        self.__read_lock = lock.Lock(self.__cache,
                                    self.__read_lock_name,
                                    RedisLockParams.TIMEOUT.value,
                                    RedisLockParams.SLEEP_TIME.value,
                                    RedisLockParams.BLOCKING.value,
                                    RedisLockParams.BLOCKING_TIMEOUT.value)
        
        # init the write lock
        self.__write_lock = lock.Lock(self.__cache,
                                    self.__write_lock_name,
                                    RedisLockParams.TIMEOUT.value,
                                    RedisLockParams.SLEEP_TIME.value,
                                    RedisLockParams.BLOCKING.value,
                                    RedisLockParams.BLOCKING_TIMEOUT.value)
        

    def acquire_read_lock(self) -> bool:
        write_lock_acquired = False

        self.__read_lock.acquire()
        read_counter = self.__cache.incr(self.__read_counter_key)
        if (read_counter == 1):
            write_lock_acquired = self.__write_lock.acquire() # acquire write lock
        self.__read_lock.release()

        return write_lock_acquired

    def release_read_lock(self):
        read_lock_acquired = self.__read_lock.acquire()

        if read_lock_acquired:
            read_counter = self.__cache.decr(self.__read_counter_key)
            if read_counter == 0:
                if self.__write_lock.owned():
                    self.__write_lock.release()
                else: # if the lock was not owned, just take its token and override
                    write_lock_token = self.__cache.get(self.__write_lock_name)
                    self.__write_lock.local.token = write_lock_token
                    self.__write_lock.release()
            self.__read_lock.release()

    def acquire_write_lock(self) -> bool:
        return self.__write_lock.acquire()

    def release_write_lock(self) -> None:
        self.__write_lock.release()
```

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same issue.

*"LockNotOwnedError("Cannot release a lock"\nredis.exceptions.LockNotOwnedError: Cannot release a lock that's no longer owned"*

redis = Redis.from_url(redis_url)

```
    try:
        with redis.lock(name, timeout=timeout, blocking_timeout=blocking_timeout) as redis_lock:
            yield redis_lock
    except RedisLockError as e:
        logger.warning("Cannot acquire lock", name=name, timeout=timeout, blocking_timeout=blocking_timeout)
        raise LockError(f"Cannot acquire lock {name}") from e
```

Can someone add some hints?